# How to generate sql col with binary function in DolphinDB script?

Tags: database, scripting, dolphindb

In DolphinDB script, I can generate SQL queries on the fly with functions like `sql`, `sqlCol`, etc. But I found that [`sqlCol`](https://dolphindb.com/help/sqlCol.html) only support unary functions, the following script doesn't work.

```
t = table(1..10 as c0, 1..10 as c1)
query = sql(sqlCol([c0, c1], add))
ans = query.eval()
```

What if I have a binary function calculating two columns, what should I do to generate this kind of SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following scripts.

```
query = sql(<c0 +c1 as c2>, t)
query = sql(sqlColAlias(expr(<c0>, add, <c1>), "c2"), t)
query = sql(sqlColAlias(makeCall(add, <c0>, <c1>), "c2"), t)
query = sql(sqlColAlias(makeCall(add, sqlCol("c0"), sqlCol("c1")), "c2"), t)
```